# Linq query with first or default join

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, linq-query-syntax

I have the following data model:

```
public class Course
{
    public int CourseId { get; set; }
    public int StateId { get; set; }
}

public class CompletedCourse
{
    public int CompletedCourseId { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public Course Course { get; set; }
    public string LicenseNumber { get; set; }
}

public class License
{
    public int LicenseId { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public int StateId { get; set; }
    public string LicenseNumber { get; set; } 
}
```

I'm trying to come up with an `IQueryable` for `CompletedCourses` and I would like to populate `CompletedCourse.LicenseNumber` with the `LicenseNumber` property of the `FirstOrDefault()` selection from my Licenses table where `UserId` and `StateId` match the completed course records.

Here is my query, but I don't think this will handle duplicate licenses correctly:

```
var entries =
    (from course in context.CompletedCourses
         join license in context.Licenses on course.UserId equals license.UserId
         where license.StateId == course.Course.StateId
         select course)
    .Include(x => x.Agent)
    .Include(x => x.Course.State);
```

Is this something that can be done in a single query?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: In the `CompletedCourse` table, isn't there a `LicenseNumber` column? How does EF know not to create one since you have a property for it?

Comment: @YacoubMassad: It's more so needed by my ViewModel.  In my EntityConfiguration for the CompletedCourse entity, I'm ignoring that property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@IvanStoev's answer was very helpful in joining on anonymous types, but ultimately I couldn't use it because I needed Includes.  Here is the solution I went with that results in two DB queries instead of one which is fine for my situation.

```
var entries = context.CompletedCourses
    .Include(x => x.Agent)
    .Include(x => x.Course);
var courses = entries.ToList();
var courseIds = entries.Select(x => x.CompletedCourseId);
var licenses =
    (from course in entries
        join license in context.Licenses
        on new { course.AgentId, course.Course.StateId } 
        equals new { AgentId = license.UserId, license.StateId }
        where courseIds.Contains(course.CompletedCourseId)
        select license);
foreach (var course in courses)
{
    var license = agentLicenses.FirstOrDefault(x => x.UserId == course.AgentId && 
        x.StateId == course.Course.StateId);
    if (license != null)
    {
        course.LicenseNumber = license.LicenseNumber;
    }
}
return courses;
```

Answer (score 8):

Here is how you can do that:

```
var entries =
    (from course in context.CompletedCourses
     join license in context.Licenses
     on new { course.UserId, course.Course.StateId }
     equals new { license.UserId, license.StateId }
     into licenses
     let licenseNumber = licenses.Select(license => license.LicenseNumber).FirstOrDefault()
     select new { course, licenseNumber });
```

But please note that with this type of projection you cannot have `Include`s in your query (you can, but they will not be in effect).

The EF generated query I'm getting from the above is:

```
SELECT 
    [Extent1].[CompletedCourseId] AS [CompletedCourseId], 
    [Extent1].[UserId] AS [UserId], 
    [Extent1].[LicenseNumber] AS [LicenseNumber], 
    [Extent1].[Course_CourseId] AS [Course_CourseId], 
    (SELECT TOP (1) 
        [Extent2].[LicenseNumber] AS [LicenseNumber]
        FROM  [dbo].[Licenses] AS [Extent2]
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[Courses] AS [Extent3] ON [Extent3].[StateId] = [Extent2].[StateId]
        WHERE ([Extent1].[Course_CourseId] = [Extent3].[CourseId]) AND ([Extent1].[UserId] = [Extent2].[UserId])) AS [C1]
    FROM [dbo].[CompletedCourses] AS [Extent1]
```

It can be noticed that EF effectively ignores the `join`, so the same result can be obtained by simple natural query:

```
var entries =
    (from course in db.CompletedCourses
     let licenseNumber =
        (from license in db.Licenses
         where license.UserId == course.UserId && license.StateId == course.Course.StateId
         select license.LicenseNumber).FirstOrDefault()
     select new { course, licenseNumber });
```

Comment: When I do that, I get the following compilation error where the word `join` has the red squiggly underline in Visual Studio: `The type of one of the expressions in the join clause is incorrect.  Type inference failed in the call to 'GroupJoin'.`  It doesn't appear to like the `on` expression...

Comment: Also, includes are imperative.

Comment: @im1dermike (1) I had a typo (`course.StateId`) which is fixed. (2) They are, but do not work with anonymous projection

Comment: If you still get the compilation error, then your actual model classes are different from the posted, because I've copied/pasted them in my EF test environment and the query compiles and executes w/o a problem.

Comment: Is there a using library I need for this to work?  System.Linq.Dynamic?

Comment: No, that's a standard LINQ.

Comment: [How to: Join by Using Composite Keys (C# Programming Guide)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb907099.aspx)

Comment: Indeed the model is slightly different.  License's property is `UserId` and the issue was that the the anonymous type AND names weren't the same.  See my post.

Comment: I saw it. So the conclusion is that it can't be done with single query because of the `Include` requirement. But, it's your query, so if the way you found works for you, it works for me - issue closed :) Happy coding!

Comment: I did learn about joining on anonymous types so thanks again for that!